# Nesting a list using a comprehension?

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
['EFJAJCOWSS', 'SDGKSRFDFF', 'ASRJDUSKLK', 'HEANDNDJWA', 'ANSDNCNEOP', 'PMSNFHHEJE', 'JEPQLYNXDL']
```

From this list how do I create a sub list:

```
[['EFJAJCOWSS'], ['SDGKSRFDFF'], ['ASRJDUSKLK'], ['HEANDNDJWA'], ['ANSDNCNEOP'], ['PMSNFHHEJE'], ['JEPQLYNXDL']]
```

Using a list comprehension in Python?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [45]: lis=['EFJAJCOWSS', 'SDGKSRFDFF', 'ASRJDUSKLK', 'HEANDNDJWA', 'ANSDNCNEOP', 'PMSNFHHEJE', 'JEPQLYNXDL']

In [46]: [[x] for x in lis]
Out[46]: 
[['EFJAJCOWSS'],
 ['SDGKSRFDFF'],
 ['ASRJDUSKLK'],
 ['HEANDNDJWA'],
 ['ANSDNCNEOP'],
 ['PMSNFHHEJE'],
 ['JEPQLYNXDL']]
```

or use `map()`:

```
In [47]: map(lambda x:[x],lis)
Out[47]: 
[['EFJAJCOWSS'],
 ['SDGKSRFDFF'],
 ['ASRJDUSKLK'],
 ['HEANDNDJWA'],
 ['ANSDNCNEOP'],
 ['PMSNFHHEJE'],
 ['JEPQLYNXDL']]
```

Comment: It's worth saying that as soon as you use ``lambda``, you shouldn't be using ``map()``. It's less readable and slower.